# Reinforcement Learning Batch Data Useage

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I am implementing a Deep Q-Learning algorithm. One thing I'm not fully getting my head around is the step where you take your batch sample from the experience queue and use that to calc the q values for the next states. This includes a secondary question about the input shape of the cnn that I'm training the policy to. My question is conceptual; do I pass the entire sampled batch into the model all at once or 1 at a time, then calculate the loss? If the entire batch that implies my CNN needs that batch size at the input layer and that when I implement the policy, I'll need to collect that number of batches before calling the inference function.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Question regarding sampling -

The purpose of sampling from the replay buffer is to train your deep neural network. DQN is an off-policy algorithm. Therefore, even though you are following an epsilon greedy policy (usually), your agent can learn a better policy from the minibatch of sampled experiences. We randomly sample the replay buffer so that your data follows the i.i.d assumption.

Question regarding batch size -

Most DL frameworks are set up so that your network can take in a varying batch size as input or have a simple [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606995/how-to-change-the-batch-size-during-training) for it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I do understand the reason for the random sampling and how it is necessary in order to not violate the MDP requirement. My misunderstanding is more implementation-centric I guess. When I'm doing a prediction and I call model(batch_of_vectors), I need to have the input_shape of the model include a batch size or it complains.

Comment: To me that suggests, when I train this model and I'm ready to deploy it, I'll have to collect a batch of states and pass that entire batch instead of a single state. If that's the case my resource requirements will need to be much higher than if I were just capturing a single image, let's say, and passing that to the cnn policy. Sorry if my questions are super clear.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: Also, when you deploy the model, you probably won't be training it. Therefore, you'll only be using a single batch size